# How to resolve Django Administration Problem with "no such table"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I am able to follow the instructions for Creation and Activation for Database Model from the book "Django for Beginners" by William S. Vincent. I am able to reach the first image, but then after that 'get' and 'post' requests probably are not working.
adding my code for models.py :

```
    from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

The following is from admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Post
admin.site.register(Post)
```

[image: 1. I am able to follow the instructions to this point given in the book "Django for Beginners" by William S. Vincent but when I am trying to save the content getting the following error]

[image: 2. this is the error browser page]

Comment: Can you check the migrations for post model? was the migrations done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you missed makemigrations or migrate thus the table is not available in the DB itself.

So run the following commands:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

If the above didn't work, drop the DB and try these once again.

Comment: but eventually, I have done these steps, probably I had to stop the server this time and have run the program.